# Image based conditionals in HTML Web Page output

Tags: javascript, html, image, conditional-statements

So, I am pretty new to HTML and javascript and I have a class assignment where I am trying to build a web page. My project is to give suggestions regarding NBA draft players given the user selects attributes. Here is the code that I have worked upon till now:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>NBA Draft Player Suggestion</title>

</head>



<body style="background-color:powderblue;">

  <style>
    body {
      background-image: url('img4.jpg');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: cover;
    }
  </style>


  <font color="white">


    <h1>NBA Draft Prediction</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h2> Choose the required position </h2>
    <select id="Position" onchange="random()">
      <option>Choose Position</option>
      <option value="Center">Center</option>
      <option value="Scoring Forward">Scoring Forward</option>
      <option value="Slashing Forward">Slashing Forward</option>
      <option value="Two Way Forward">Two Way Forward</option>
      <option value="Combo Guard">Combo Guard</option>
      <option value="Scoring Guard">Scoring Guard</option>
      <option value="Passing Guard">Passing Guard</option>
      <option value="Play Maker">Play Maker</option>
    </select>

    <br>
    <br> You have Chosen the position of:
    <div id="output"></div>

    <!--
  <br>
  <h2> Choose the required Skills</h2>

  <form name="skills" method="post">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="j1" value="Height" class="anyclass"id="ch1"/> Height</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="j2" value="Weight" class="anyclass" id="ch2"/> Weight</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="j3" value="ArmLength" class="anyclass"  id="ch3"/> Arm Length</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="j4" value="FingerLength" class="anyclass" id="ch4"/> Finger Length </label><br>
-->
    <h3>You have chosen:<br>
      <textarea name="type" rows="5" cols="10"></textarea>
      <!--
<br><br>
      <button name="btn" onclick="random()">Get Result</button>

</font>

<!--
      
<a href="NBA_2nd_Page.html" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Click Here To Go To Next Page</a>
-->

<!--
      <script>
        var val = 0,
          form = document.forms.skills,
          text = skills.elements.type;
        form.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
          var checkboxes = form.querySelectorAll("[type='checkbox']");
          text.value = "";
          Array.from(checkboxes).forEach(function(checkbox) {

            if (checkbox.checked) {
              text.value += checkbox.value + "\n";
            }
          });
        });

        function random() {
          var a = document.getElementById("Position").value;
          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = a;

          if (a == 'Center' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true) {
            alert('Player1');
          } else if (a == 'Center' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true) {
            alert('Player2');
          } else if (a == 'Center' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player3');
          } else if (a == 'Center' && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true) {
            alert('Player4');
          } else if (a == 'Centre' && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player5');
          } else if (a == 'Center' && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player6');
          } else if (a == 'Scoring Forward' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true) {
            alert('Player1');
          } else if (a == 'Scoring Forward' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true) {
            alert('Player2');
          } else if (a == 'Scoring Forward' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player3');
          } else if (a == 'Scoring Forward' && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true) {
            alert('Player4');
          } else if (a == 'Scoring Forward' && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player5');
          } else if (a == 'Scoring Forward' && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player6');
          } else if (a == 'Slashing Forward' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true) {
            alert('Player1');
          } else if (a == 'Slashing Forward' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true) {
            alert('Player2');
          } else if (a == 'Slashing Forward' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player3');
          } else if (a == 'Slashing Forward' && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true) {
            alert('Player4');
          } else if (a == 'Slashing Forward' && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player5');
          } else if (a == 'Slashing Forward' && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player6');
          } else if (a == 'Two Way Forward' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true) {
            alert('Player1');
          } else if (a == 'Two Way Forward' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true) {
            alert('Player2');
          } else if (a == 'Two Way Forward' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player3');
          } else if (a == 'Two Way Forward' && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true) {
            alert('Player4');
          } else if (a == 'Two Way Forward' && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player5');
          } else if (a == 'Two Way Forward' && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player6');
          } else if (a == 'Combo Guard' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true) {
            alert('Player1');
          } else if (a == 'Combo Guard' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true) {
            alert('Player2');
          } else if (a == 'Combo Guard' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player3');
          } else if (a == 'Combo Guard' && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true) {
            alert('Player4');
          } else if (a == 'Combo Guard' && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player5');
          } else if (a == 'Combo Guard' && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player6');
          } else if (a == 'Scoring Guard' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true) {
            alert('Player1');
          } else if (a == 'Scoring Guard' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true) {
            alert('Player2');
          } else if (a == 'Scoring Guard' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player3');
          } else if (a == 'Scoring Guard' && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true) {
            alert('Player4');
          } else if (a == 'Scoring Guard' && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player5');
          } else if (a == 'Scoring Guard' && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player6');
          } else if (a == 'Passing Guard' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true) {
            alert('Player1');
          } else if (a == 'Passing Guard' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true) {
            alert('Player2');
          } else if (a == 'Passing Guard' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player3');
          } else if (a == 'Passing Guard' && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true) {
            alert('Player4');
          } else if (a == 'Passing Guard' && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player5');
          } else if (a == 'Passing Guard' && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player6');
          } else if (a == 'Play Maker' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true) {
            alert('Player1');
          } else if (a == 'Play Maker' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true) {
            alert('Player2');
          } else if (a == 'Play Maker' && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player3');
          } else if (a == 'Play Maker' && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true) {
            alert('Player4');
          } else if (a == 'Play Maker' && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player5');
          } else if (a == 'Play Maker' && document.getElementById("ch3").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch4").checked == true) {
            alert('Player6,Player7');
          }
-->




        }
      </script>


</body>

</html>
```

So what I want is that given that the user chooses an option say "Center", two images are to appear  below of players and a button just below the picture. Once the button is selected, the names of the players are to appear on the text area. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Any other ideas regarding the images are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent hardcoding the possible options an event listener can be used that listens for changes of a select. This can be combined by filtering and generating HTML for an interactive experience. Checkout the demo below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>NBA Draft Prediction</h1>
    <div id="filters">

    </div>

    <div id="results">

    </div>
</body>
<script>
    var playersByPosition = [
        {
            name: 'Center',
            players: [
              {name: 'player1', image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/80x80'},
              {name: 'player2', image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/80x80'},
            ],
        },
        {
            name: 'Scoring Forward',
            players: [
              {name: 'player3', image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/80x80'},
              {name: 'player4', image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/80x80'},
            ],
        },
        {
            name: 'Slashing Forward',
            players: [
              {name: 'player5', image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/80x80'},
              {name: 'player6', image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/80x80'},
            ],
        },
        {
            name: 'Two Way Forward',
            players: [
              {name: 'player7', image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/80x80'},
              {name: 'player8', image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/80x80'},
            ],
        },
        {
            name: 'Combo Guard',
            players: [
              {name: 'player9', image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/80x80'},
              {name: 'player10', image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/80x80'},
            ],
        },
        {
            name: 'Scoring Guard',
            players: [
              {name: 'player11', image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/80x80'},
              {name: 'player12', image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/80x80'},
            ],
        },
        {
            name: 'Passing Guard',
            players: [
              {name: 'player13', image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/80x80'},
              {name: 'player14', image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/80x80'},
            ],
        },
        {
            name: 'Play Maker',
            players: [
              {name: 'player15', image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/80x80'},
              {name: 'player16', image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/80x80'},
            ],
        }
    ];

    var buildSelectors = function(positions){
        var options = positions.map(function(position){
           return '<option>' + position.name + '</option>';
        }).join('');

        return '<select class="filter" name="positions">'+options+'</select>';
    }

    var filtersElem = document.querySelector('#filters');
    var resultsElem = document.querySelector('#results');

    filtersElem.innerHTML = buildSelectors(playersByPosition);

    var filterResultsForFilterValue = function(value){
        var selectedPosition = playersByPosition.find(function(position){
            return position.name === value;
        });

        var formattedResults = selectedPosition.players.map(function(player){
            return '<div><h3>Player: ' + player.name + '</h3><img src="'+player.image+'"</div>';
        }).join('');

        resultsElem.innerHTML = formattedResults;
    };


    document.querySelectorAll('.filter').forEach(function (filter) {
        filter.addEventListener('change',function (e) {
            var selectedPosition = playersByPosition.find(function(position){
               return position.name === e.currentTarget.value;
            });

            filterResultsForFilterValue(selectedPosition.name)
        })
    })

    filterResultsForFilterValue(playersByPosition[0].name)

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. However, instead of names like "Player1" and "Player3", I actually want images of players.

Comment: I updated the example to include a name and image. @Benjamin